# appcelerator tableview autosliding

Tags: iphone, appcelerator

Using Appcelerator:

I have a form, a tableView with textFeilds

I want it so when I focus on them, it slides the window or the view to the top, under the navigation bar.

Right now, the keyboard is blocking the last few rows.

Do I need a listener on each form to slide? If so how do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a focus listener to each of your textFields.

Then you should be able to move the tableview using scrollToTop or scrollToIndex.

If there are a fixed number of textfields you might want to try using a scrollview instead of a tableview. This will handle the move-up action for you when the individual taps in a textfield.